# trigger is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

trigger is not working in angular js

```
 $http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: partial_path + '/test.php',
     data: 'action=create&d=' + localStorage.getItem('lastid'),
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }
 }).success(function(data) {
     if (data != "error") {
         var url = partial_path + '/' + data;
         //alert(url);
         $("#hreflink").attr("href", url);
         $('#hreflink').trigger('click');
     }
 });
```

Hi i am new to angular js

Trigger event is not working in angular js ajax loaded template

Please help to fix this issue

**Updated**

window.open(url, '_blank');

window.open is working but its ask popup browser alert

Comment: Why are you using `trigger`? You can use `$location.path(url)`.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library or are you using the included jqLite ?

Comment: @Satpal I need to open in new tab witout popup alert

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console ?

Comment: @Kaz no error in console

Answer (score 0):

> Trigger event is not working in angular js ajax loaded template

Try to do it in angular way. Also make use of `$timeout`. Trigger the click using

```
$timeout(function(){
 angular.element('#hreflink').trigger('click');
},0)
```

Comment: @Satpal yes I second that however I am trying to answer to his `trigger` problem

Comment: @DeebanBabu You need to inject it in you controller first, just like you injected `$http`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79121/discussion-between-deeban-babu-and-zee).

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if you haven't loaded jquery BEFORE angular in your HTML page, otherwise you'll have to use jqLite or as @Satpal suggested use the $location service:

```
$location.path(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call this script in the Directive?

use:

```
   var elem = jQuery(element);
 $timeout(function () {
   elem.find('#hreflink').trigger('click');
 }, 100);
```